# Passing Object Through Provider React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know what is happening to my code. I'm passing some variables to my provider. `getArticles` is working as well, but data which is an object is not passing. It seems working well but on my component I can't see the data.

services/api.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api'},
);
```

hooks/ArticlesProviders.js

```
export default AppProviders;
export default api;
    import React, {useCallback, useState} from 'react'; 
    import api from '../services/api';

export const ArticleContext = React.createContext()

export const ArticlesProvider = ({children}) => {
const [data, setData] = useState('')

const getArticles = useCallback(async () => {
const response = await api
  .get('articles', {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'token 03d379c9e9d9bc74eaf38fccd66c94a2ade8a45c'
    },
  })
  
  console.log("dentro da API: ", response.data) // WORKING 
  setData(request.data)

  })
  return (
// in this line data object is not passing???
    <ArticleContext.Provider value={{data, getArticles, x: "Contexto"}}>
      {children}
    </ArticleContext.Provider>
  )

}
```

hooks/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { ArticlesProvider } from './ArticlesProvider';

const AppProviders = ({children}) => {

return (
    <ArticlesProvider>
      {children}
    </ArticlesProvider>
  )}
```

routes/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserForm from '../components/Forms/UserForm';
import Articles from '../pages/Articles';

import AppProviders from '../hooks';

const Routes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <AppProviders>
      <Route path="/login" exact component={UserForm} />
      <Route path="/articles" component={Articles} />
    </AppProviders> 
  </Switch>
)

export default Routes;
```

components/Posts/index.js

```
...
import { ArticleContext } from '../../hooks/ArticlesProvider';
import { useStyles } from './styles';

export default function Post() {
  const hooked = useContext(ArticleContext)
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([])
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const apiData = hooked.getArticles()
    console.log("Data: ", hooked.data) //Bringing nothing
    console.log("Dados teste: ", hooked.x) //printting 
    console.log("Dentro do comp: ", apiData) // printing 
  },[])
...
```

Comment: where are you attempting to use the context variables? I would need to see that as well. Are you also wrapping your application in the context provider as well?

Comment: is the API call made when you click on `getArticles` inside your consumer ?